404: This page could not be found from ai/react/vercel's ai, err occurred in chatbot standalone comp, when called from other components except home /
`chatbot standalone is a next component attached in next layout, messaging and streaming handled by ai/react or vercel's lib and markdown lib.
working perfectly fine when requested or chat from home component "/", below error occur's in all other components when requested from other components (at client level or browser, there is no request to server or route api when called from other comp), despite of it chatbot is a fixed standalone component.
`
error : 
Error: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style data-next-hide-fouc="true">body{display:none}</style><noscript data-next-hide-fouc="true"><style>body{display:block}</style></noscript><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/><title>404: This page could not be found</title><meta name="next-head-count" content="3"/><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1718954794410"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1718954794410" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1718954794410" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1718954794410" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_error.js?ts=1718954794410" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1718954794410" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1718954794410" defer=""></script><noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript></head><body><div id="__next"><div style="font-family:system-ui,&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,&quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;,&quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;;height:100vh;text-align:center;display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;justify-content:center"><div style="line-height:48px"><style>body{color:#000;background:#fff;margin:0}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{color:#fff;background:#000}.next-error-h1{border-right:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}</style><h1 class="next-error-h1" style="display:inline-block;margin:0 20px 0 0;padding-right:23px;font-size:24px;font-weight:500;vertical-align:top">404</h1><div style="display:inline-block"><h2 style="font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:28px">This page could not be found<!-- -->.</h2></div></div></div></div><script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1718954794410"></script><script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"statusCode":404}},"page":"/_error","query":{},"buildId":"development","isFallback":false,"gip":true,"scriptLoader":[]}</script></body></html>
    at callChatApi (index.mjs:486:11)
    at async getStreamedResponse (index.mjs:717:10)
    at async processChatStream (index.mjs:552:42)
    at async eval (index.mjs:815:9)

here is the link of the github file chatbot, too large to paste code
here is deployed webapp decentBet .
please feel to share any solution`
